# How can i escape a string when running in SQL?

Tags: sql, ssms

I am trying to run the following in SSMS:

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
           WHERE name = 'test.'user')  
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [test.'user] 
         WITH PASSWORD = 'test'123', 
         DEFAULT_DATABASE = TestDB, 
         DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english], 
         CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,  
         CHECK_POLICY = OFF  
 END
```

It gives an error:

```
   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string.
```

This is because the password has a single quote.
How can i escape the password and username to fix this ?

Comment: dont i need to set the password first , how do i set the password ?

Comment: Will this work ?
Escaping those with another single quotes ?

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
               WHERE name = 'test''user')  
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [test''user] 
         WITH PASSWORD = 'test''123', `

Comment: that will work , but the sql is generated from c# and i wont know exactly where the ' is . Also what if they use other characters ? So looking to escape the string before it comes to sql

Comment: Try this:  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
           WHERE name = 'test.user')  
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN sellis
         WITH PASSWORD = 'test123', 
         DEFAULT_DATABASE = TestDB, 
         DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english], 
         CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,  
         CHECK_POLICY = OFF  
 END